# Mygento JQuery Lib is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, magento

I want to use Jquery UI on my magento website, so I installed Mygento JQuery which seems to have the jQuery UI module.

But I still have the error: *jQuery is not defined*

How am I supposed to use Mygento Jquery Library?

Thanks.

Comment: are you loading jquery before magento? please show some code.

Comment: I don't know. am I supposed to add some code?

Comment: yes, we can't solve your problem unless you show us what's wrong.

Comment: Try to use jQuery.noConflict() at the end of jquery script

Comment: I just found that there is some configurations in the system configuration of magento to allowed Mygento jQuery to work. But still not working.

Comment: I edited my post since I found a way to solve the problem. Mygento JQuery Library is realy cool since you don't have to manage jQuery updates and you don't have to change some core files. You should probably take a look at this extension.

Comment: if you solved the problem, you should submit it as an answer -- editing the question sort of just leaves it open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Once you have Mygento JQuery installed in your magento website, you need to do two things:

1. copy the folder app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/mygento to your own package app/design/frontend/default/layout
2. go to your admin panel, and System->Configuration->Mygento Extensions->jQuery Library and here you can enable the plugins you want to be loaded.